# Syntax error in object.h file from python3.10-dev package

Tags: compiling, python3, c++, cmake, qt-creator

I am writing a code to edit Sqlite database from c++ and then using PyBind11 to use the program with python. I installed PyBind11, built it till here no issue but when I am building the code it shows an error:

```
/usr/include/python3.10/object.h:227: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘;’ token
In file included from /usr/include/python3.10/Python.h:74,
                 from /usr/local/include/pybind11/detail/common.h:266,
                 from /usr/local/include/pybind11/attr.h:13,
                 from /usr/local/include/pybind11/detail/class.h:12,
                 from /usr/local/include/pybind11/pybind11.h:13,
                 from /media/raghav/Sector 16/core/database.cpp:21:
/usr/include/python3.10/object.h:227:23: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘;’ token
  227 |     PyType_Slot *slots; /* terminated by slot==0. */
      |                       ^
```

Else, my code works fine but I am stuck at this thing. I am using the following things:

1. Ubuntu
2. CMake 3.24.2
3. Qt Creator 10
4. Python 3.10.6

Please help me out.
Thanks in advance

Comment: I suspect the issue is similar to [expected unqualified-id before ‘;’ token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7292558/expected-unqualified-id-before-token) i.e. a pre-processor directive (perhaps from an earlier Qt header in your code) that is stomping on the PyType_Spec struct's `slots` variable name.

Comment: Why no version info for Ubuntu, it needs to be there.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for you support. The solution was to import pybind11 before importing Qt modules and using the `#define PYBIND11_NO_KEYWORDS`